# xml nodes editing based on an xmlElement

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have tried two ways but they both didnt work..
the first way::

```
string filepath = Server.MapPath[this is not a link]("XMLFile2.xml");
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
                xdoc.Load(filepath);

                XmlNode root = xdoc.DocumentElement;
                XmlNode idNode = root.SelectSingleNode("/students/student/id");
if (idNode.Value == 9.ToString())
                    {
                        var nodeOfStudent = xdoc.SelectNodes("/students/student[@id='9']");
                        nodeOfStudent[1].InnerXml = TextBox_firstname.Text;
                        nodeOfStudent[2].InnerXml = TextBox_lastname.Text;
                        nodeOfStudent[3].InnerXml = TextBox_dob.Text;
                        nodeOfStudent[4].InnerXml = TextBox_class.Text;
                        nodeOfStudent[5].InnerXml = TextBox_section.Text;
                        nodeOfStudent[6].InnerXml = TextBox_telephone.Text;

                    }
```

the second way::

```
string filepath = Server.MapPath("XMLFile2.xml");
                XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
                xdoc.Load(filepath);

                XmlNode root = xdoc.DocumentElement;
                XmlNode idNode = root.SelectSingleNode("/students/student/id");

xdoc.SelectSingleNode("/students/student[@id='10']/firstname").InnerXml = TextBox_firstname.Text;
                        xdoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(firstname);
                        xdoc.SelectSingleNode("/students/student[@id='10']/lastname").InnerXml = TextBox_firstname.Text;
                        xdoc.SelectSingleNode("/students/student[@id='10']/dob").InnerXml = TextBox_firstname.Text;
                        xdoc.SelectSingleNode("/students/student[@id='10']/class").InnerXml = TextBox_firstname.Text;
                        xdoc.SelectSingleNode("/students/student[@id='10']/section").InnerXml = TextBox_firstname.Text;
                        xdoc.SelectSingleNode("/students/student[@id='10']/telephone").InnerXml = TextBox_firstname.Text;

                        xdoc.Save(filepath);
```

is there something wrong i dont see...
my xml file looks like this::

```
<students>
  <student>
    <id>1</id>
    <first_name>ahmad</first_name>
    <last_name>hani</last_name>
    <DOB>12/5/1998</DOB>
    <class>sixth</class>
    <section>A</section>
    <telephone>06555632</telephone>
  </student>  
</students>
```

and i used a query string to load the values from a gridView located in another page using "QueryString"....

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this with Linq to xml:

```
int id = 9;
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(filepath);
var student = xdoc.Descendants("student")
                  .Where(s => (int)s.Element("id") == id)
                  .SingleOrDefault();

if (student != null)
{
    student.Element("first_name").Value = TextBox_firstname.Text;
    student.Element("last_name").Value = TextBox_lastname.Text;
    student.Element("DOB").Value = TextBox_dob.Text;
    student.Element("class").Value = TextBox_class.Text;
    // etc
}

xdoc.Save(filepath);
```

Comment: i want to filter my code based on id xmlelement value,, but it doesn't seem to be working!!!
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(filepath);
                
XmlNode root = xdoc.DocumentElement;
XmlNode idNode = root.SelectSingleNode("/students/student/id");

           if (idNode.Value == null){create a new xml node}
else if (idNode.Value != null) {create a new xml element with the value of id)

i tried to explain it in question, here is the link...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607387/edit-xml-elements-of-a-specific-node-based-on-its-id-element-asp-net-page